# Catel MVVM How set two different Item Sources within one ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, catel

I am trying to create a view that has a list of expanders and I want when I press to expand one of them a list of names from a different item source to be loaded. So far What I get is when I set the item source to LineRouteCollection to set the header of the expander, even though I bind the expander to show the names from AllStopsCollection the binding "Name" shows the names from the LineRouteCollection source and not the names from AllStopsCollection as I want. Can you take a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
<ListBox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineRouteCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" MinHeight="70">                            
                    <ListBox >
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource ="{Binding AllStopsCollection}">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </ItemsControl>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ListBox>
```

EDIT:

In my View model I load the observable collections (AllStopsCollection & LineRouteCollection) like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Route> AllLineRoutes;
private ObservableCollection<StopView> AllRouteStops;

//List of all Routes connected to the selected line
public ObservableCollection<Route> LineRouteCollection // Must be property or DP to be bound!
{
    get { return AllLineRoutes; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, AllLineRoutes)) return;
        AllLineRoutes = value;
    }
}


//List of all stops
public ObservableCollection<StopView> AllStopsCollection // Must be property or DP to be bound!
{
    get { return AllRouteStops; }
    set
    {
        if (Equals(value, AllRouteStops)) return;
        AllRouteStops = value;
    }
}
```

And I fill the collection with data in the constructor of the class. I am loading the data correctly and I can see it but it just wont appear in the textbox after the expander is expand.

Comment: The issue here is that you need to provide an `ItemTemplate` instead of nesting a textbox instead the `ItemsControl`. You should have the same setup as you have for the first `ItemsControl` in the inner `ItemsControl` with an `ItemsControl.ItemTemplate` containing the textblock, otherwise the binding scope for the textblock is the binding scope of the first `DataTemplate`

Comment: I've updated my answer - your issue is with binding scopes (I was expecting you to have a hierarchy of model data not two flat collections!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have provided an `ItemTemplate` for the first `ItemsControl`, but the inner `ItemsControl` contains a `TextBlock` which is just nested inside the control

You need to specify an `ItemTemplate` for the inner control too

```
<ListBox>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LineRouteCollection}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" MinHeight="70">                            
                    <ListBox>
                        <ItemsControl ItemsSource ="{Binding AllStopsCollection}">
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> <!-- You forgot this ItemTemplate -->
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                               </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl>
                   </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</ListBox>
```

Otherwise the binding scope for the most inner `TextBlock` is going to be the same as the inner `ItemsControl` resulting in the problem you are seeing

Not sure why you have an `ItemsControl` inside a `ListBox` though..? Did you want multiple `Expanders` inside a `ListBox` rather than a single list item?

This one works fine for me:

```
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LineRoutes}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" MinHeight="70">
                    <ListBox ItemsSource ="{Binding AllStops}">
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <!-- You forgot this ItemTemplate -->
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

[image: Example of nested expanders in listbox]

Is that what you wanted?

**Edit:**

Ok in light of your updates I can see what the error is

You want to keep your eyes peeled for binding errors in your output window.

The `AllStopsCollection` is not a child of `LineRouteCollection` so the `DataContext` for the inner control is pointing to a `Route` not the `ViewModel`.

In order to bind to the collection of `Stop`s you need to make sure you point the binding to a control that has the `ViewModel` as it's `DataContext`. The easiest way is to use an `ElementName` binding and bind to the root control (usually called `LayoutRoot`)

e.g.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApplication1:ViewModel}">
    <Grid Name="LayoutRoot">
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding LineRouteCollection}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Expander Header="{Binding Name}" MinHeight="70">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource ="{Binding DataContext.AllStopsCollection, ElementName=LayoutRoot}"> <!-- Provide an ElementName binding to point to the root Grid and bind to the viewmodels AllStopsCollection (viewmodel is in the DataContext) -->
                            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope that helps

The only thing to watch out for is if you need to manipulate a stop - obviously since you are binding the same collection to multiple sub-lists if you change a `Stop` item it will change the values in each one of the lists too since the references all point to the same object

Comment: Hmm I think you are right about the ItemTemplate but now tht I have fixed it the problem remains now it does not show anything. But i think you put me on the right track

Comment: Might be something to do with the nesting of controls you have - I'll see if I can produce an example

Comment: Ok I've updated, it seems like you are trying to nest `ItemsControl` inside controls - a `ListBox` *is* an `ItemsControl` so you don't need one nested inside a `ListBox`. I assume you want two listboxes, one nested inside another with different item sources

Comment: Yeah this is what I wanted but. I still cant see the stops when the expander is pressed ;/

Comment: The weird thing is that I can load the names of the stops as names of the headers but I cant load the content in the list box in the expander.

Comment: It sounds like you are just missing the data template - did you update your XAML to remove the `ItemsControl`s from inside your `ListBox`es?

Comment: yep the problem remains

Comment: I don't have the issue - can you post your full code? Including your data item declarations and full XAML again?

Comment: Oh my god thank you very much!!! This problem was bugging me for 4 days!!! GOD and it was that simple thank you again!!!

Answer (score -1):

That is one approach, try to be more dynamic. Here is a list box where I have predefined 3 different text boxes and provide values at runtime.

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="253" Margin="10,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="734">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid x:Name="grid" Margin="0,2">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="234" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="143" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding String1}"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding String2}" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding String3}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Code Behind :

```
    public class Class1
    {
        public string String1 { get; set; }
        public string String2 { get; set; }
        public string String3 { get; set; }
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            ListBox1.Items.Add((new Class1()
            {
                String1 = "Apple",
                String2 = "Car",
                String3 = "Tree"
            }));
    }
```

**OR**

If you want a solution that is more dynamic at runtime, you can do something like this:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
                Grid WholeGrid = new Grid();
                WholeGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef2 = new ColumnDefinition();
                ColumnDefinition colDef3 = new ColumnDefinition();
                WholeGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
                WholeGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef2);
                WholeGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef3);

                // Create Question Lable
                Label QuestionLabel = new Label();
                QuestionLabel.Content = "Apple";
                Grid.SetRow(QuestionLabel, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(QuestionLabel, 0);

                // Create Date Picker
                DatePicker newDatePicker = new DatePicker();
                newDatePicker.Width = 200;
                newDatePicker.Height = 20;
                Grid.SetRow(newDatePicker, 0);
                Grid.SetColumn(newDatePicker, 1);

                // Add to Lable and Date Picker
                WholeGrid.Children.Add(QuestionLabel);
                WholeGrid.Children.Add(newDatePicker);
                ListBox1.Items.Add(WholeGrid);
    }
```

Comment: This is not a very MVVM friendly way of doing anything and also doesn't answer the OPs question in any way